# Execute the jquery code only if div exist

Tags: jquery, css

here is the html code :

```
<div id="popup" class="popup_block" >
 <img src="images/PUB-histRIRE.jpg" alt="popup" />
</div>
```

and script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

            popWidth = 690;
            popHeight = 550;
            popID = 'popup';

            var popMargTop = popHeight / 2;
            var popMargLeft = popWidth / 2;

            //Apply Margin to Popup
            $('#' + popID).css({ 
                'width': popWidth,
                'height': popHeight,
                'margin-top' : -popMargTop,
                'margin-left' : -popMargLeft,
                'visibility' : 'visible'
            }); 

            //Fade in Background
            $('body').append('<div id="fade"></div>'); //Add the fade layer to bottom of the body tag.
            $('#fade').css({'filter' : 'alpha(opacity=80)'}).fadeIn(); //Fade in the fade layer 

        //Close Popups and Fade Layer
        $('a.close, #fade, .popup_block').live('click', function() { //When clicking on the close or fade layer...
            $('#fade , .popup_block').fadeOut(); //fade them both out
            $('#fade').remove();
            return false;
        }); 

    });
    </script>
```

I like to execute the code only on page with the div... on page without thi div, just ignore. I can make a if by parsin the URL... but it look more complicated to me... any simple jquery trick ?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
if($('#popup').length >0 ){
   //your code here 
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Like this:

```
if($('div#popup').length) {
    // div exists
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The way to do this is (or was) to check the length property like so:

```
if ($("#"+ popID).length > 0){
  // do stuff
}
```

Comment: +1 for using his popID variable. No point having the variable if you're not going to use it everywhere. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

If you need a simple reusable solution, you could extend jQuery:

```
$.fn.extend({
    'ifexists': function (callback) {
        if (this.length > 0) {
            return callback($(this));
        }
    }
});
```

Then:

```
$('#popup').ifexists(function(elem) {
    // do something...
});
```

Comment: This answer deserves more attention. Reusable code is king.

Answer (score 3):

```
if ($("#popup").length) {
  // do popup stuff
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Let's use [each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) and possibly [first](https://api.jquery.com/first/) .

If you want to execute the code on each match:

```
$("#popup").each(function(index, element){
    //Do stuff.  Use $(element) and/or index as necessary
});
```

If you want to execute the code only once if a match is found:

```
$("#popup").first().each(function(index, element){
    //Do stuff.  Use $(element) as necessary.
});
```

Comment: An ID selector will never have multiple matches, since IDs must be unique.

Comment: Using `.each()` in place of `if` will work, but it's a confusing way to do it.

Comment: @Barmar: I used an ID selector as an example (since everyone else used that as their example).  Usually this sort of thing would be done with a class selector.

Comment: The question is about testing the existence of a specific DIV with an ID, not anything with a class.

Comment: @Barmar: The OP's title question, "Execute the jquery code only if div exist".  While my solution is a more general solution to a very precise problem (and not a perfect fit), it's often the correct solution to that question (albeit, not in the OP's case).  I'm not at all attempting to help the OP (this question is more than 5 years old!); I'm trying to help future SO visitors who want to know "how to execute jquery code only if a div exists" (for which this question is the top search result).

Comment: Well, your answer is still not a great way to do it. `if ($(selector).length > 0)` is the simplest and most efficient way, and it's in the other answers. Also, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438828/jquery-how-to-test-if-selector-matches-anything) answers the general question.

Comment: @Barmar: If the reason you're asking whether your selector matches is because you want to run code to change that selector, my answer is simpler.  Admittedly, using `first().each()` is silly, since node-specific code should be safe to execute multiple times if there are multiple matches.

Comment: If you want to do something to the selected items, you just do it, you don't need to test first. That seems to be essentially what you're showing in your answer, but you never clearly explain it. But it's also not really what the question is about, it's more of a special case of the question.