# jQuery - how to test if selector matches anything?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Say I have the following:

```
$('#foo')
```

I'd like to know if that selector matches anything. How do I test for this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
if ($('#foo').length > 0) {

    // do things
}
```

should do it

Comment: Or, if you are into type coercion if ( $("#foo").length ) {} works too.

Answer (score -2):

Use a Javascript Console to see what your method call returns.  Type your command into the console, and then hit enter.

Shortcuts to open a JS console:

- Chrome: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>, then click the Console tab
- Firefox: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>

Comment: To clarify (inspired by the downvote), this method only applies if you are manually testing a page.  It affords you a level of introspection that checking the length of the query result may not.

Comment: Surely an alternate method of debugging a selector is better than a repeated answer...